# Where are photos stored in an android backup?

Tags: backup, photos

Recently I did a backup of my android using adb. I wanted to find my pictures from this backup so I extracted the .ab to a .tar file using Nikolay Elenkov's extractor. In the tar file I can't seem to find any photos. Did I mess up the backup or are the photos located somewhere else?

Comment: Did you use `-shared` in your adb command when taking backup? In fact, please mention the `adb command` you used to take backup.

Comment: @Firelord
I used `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f C:\Users\USER_NAME\backup.ab`

Comment: Corey, as @Firelord already asked you to wait for me, I feel obliged to chime in. Though I usually do *not* include shared storage with my backups (that just bloats the backup file, and restore is an all-or-nothing – so for shared-storage I rather pull the content directly), I might have one such backup left from testing it out. I can check for it later when I'm home. Firelord will ping me again if I've not done that within 4 hours, right? And you're talking about photos made with the device's camera, is that correct?

Comment: OK Corey, I took a `-shared` backup and found that the stuff is stored under the folder named `shared`. Actually, the whole SD card structure is preserved and I was able to find camera images inside `DCIM` folder and the rest of the images is in the folders equivalent to in the actual SD card. Do you not have such folder?

Comment: The only folder I have available is `apps`